# How can I parametrize an object in order to fill in a face following its features?

Tags: modeling, faces, instances

[image]
[image]

Let´s suppose I want a terracotta roof, so it's composed of terracotta tiles. the scale of this tile should not be affected. The same tile has to be multiplied along the surface as many times as necessary in order to fill it completely.

These images have been made with the JARCH add-on, but I could only do this with the presets that come with it.

I want to create this manually, with whatever object it's possible and being able to apply it to a surface in a way it's non-destructive and parametrizable.

Comment: I'm sure there are some algorithms that can cover that pretty well. Do you know how to script in python ? Otherwise you can explore the Tissue (free) add-on which might offer this functionality

Comment: Yeah, somehow that add-on works, It shouldn't be that hard. Didn't know that add-on you share with me, I´ll explore it, thanks.